# serious mouse problems

Tags: windows, mouse

I've had this on my laptop for about 3 weeks now. I have an old Logitech G5 that i work with.

On random moments whatever i click with it loses focus and i can't do anything in it. If i then pull it out and try to use my mousepad and buttons they do the same thing.
The only thing that helps most of the time is switching my dpi with the buttons on the mouse. if i switch that everything works properly again.

Whenver I try switching a tab, in example chrome, that tab closes.

Comment: Try a new mouse?

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the firmware:

Logitech G5 firmware update instructions
  http://logitech-en-amr.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/9980/section/troubleshoot/crid/428/lt_product_id/359/tabs/1,3,2,5/cl/us,en/kw/

Making sure your mouse driver software is up-to-date may be helpful too.

Additionally, since it's a laser mouse, make sure that you're using it on a surface that isn't shiny as shiny surfaces (including most plastic mouse pads) can cause the light to reflect incorrectly.